# Unexpected metadata type found when build release apk

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm trying to add facebook login.I work with build apk(debug) and no error.But i get error when i try to build release(signed) apk.

Here is ss for build.

[image]

I add google sign-in method first,and it was ok with on debug and release builds.Then i add facebook but i can get only debug build now.

I search many topics but there is no specific solution given.What should i do ?

**Gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mertg.testsignin"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following in your build.gradle (:app) inside android {} tag (below buildTypes {})

```
lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
```